# Can we create better resolution paths for questions about the Salesforce CLI (sfdx)?

Tags: discussion

A lot of users struggle with initial setup and configuration of the Salesforce CLI. Many problems fall into a small number of buckets, but the solutions to those buckets seem to often be heterogenous or site-specific, and may also change as the CLI itself changes and evolves.

I see a lot of CLI-related questions either not getting (successfully) answered at all, or getting multiple answers over time that are different or contradictory ("this worked for me!"), because the same symptoms are resolved in quite different ways in different end-user contexts.

I'm wondering about the community's thoughts on the possibility of creating one or several `canonical-qa` posts to collect our best resolution paths for specific common CLI problems, specifically, install and update problems, failure to show SFDX commands in VSC, and org authorization problems. As part of that, I'd hope we could also define when specific problems need to follow well-defined support paths, such as referrals to the CLI's GitHub repo or to local network and technical support experts.

What are your thoughts? Beneficial to our user community? Not beneficial? Needs revision?

Comment: I don't see why not. I'd be willing to contribute what I know, but that's exceptionally limited. Can we maybe get input from one of the actual CLI devs?

Comment: This is much needed. There are a lot of questions around SFDX and a troubleshooting guide would add great value